# How to "close all but this" in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've got about 100 tabs open in Photoshop (I've bulk opened them to stack an image). Now I'm getting memory/disk full errors and I need to close all the tabs but one. It's extremely impractical to close all one by one, I need to close all but one. I need to save the one but I can't save due to my scratch disk being almost full, and closing all the 20MP RAWs may help.

How do I close all tabs but one? I am on Photoshop CC 2015.

Comment: Hey Can, I don't know about closing all but 1 tabs though I'm not sure it will help you. Unless you close Photoshop entirely, it tends to keep the disk space that it has used for previously opened documents even after they have been closed individually :/ You could try purging or emptying scratch disks?

Comment: @Jenna I don't currently have space (I've ordered a new external drive though). however, Photoshop uses whatever is available: a combination of scratch disk space + real RAM. so if I close the other files, it will end up with GBs of usable memory for photoshop. it's allocated by photoshop and will still be used by photoshop so photoshop not deallocating the space wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Very good point - I'm afraid I can't find anything useful. All options seem to be close all tabs, which obviously wouldn't work. Was looking for some hacky way, like close all tabs but keep floating windows open, to no avail though. Hope you get it figured out!

Comment: @Jenna I've also tried experimenting with command/option/shift clicking etc but no avail :)

Comment: Heartbreaking, looks like you're gonna have to close so many docs! Perhaps use CTRL/CMD + 'W' rather than clicking the absurdly tiny 'x' in the corner of each tab? I use it to close tabs and when the save notification pops up I hit Y for yes (S for SAVE), N for no and C for cancel. Not a solution but maybe a little quicker.. :)

Comment: @Jenna yes, I'm using keyboard shortcuts but it still takes some time :) thank you though :)

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't you open them into a single file? 
Doesn't help now tho - but it may be quicker to start again?
From Bridge: Tools>Photoshop>Load files into Photoshop Layers
or from Psd.. File>Scripts>Load files into Stack

Comment: Yes, that was my bad. I don't know why I went that way. But still, Photoshop needs such an option as many tabbed apps nowadays have such option.

Answer (score 2):

I know the post is old but since it was bumped and never got an accepted answer, here's mine. This can be done easily with a script:

```
// this script will close all inactive documents

// change this to... 'yes' to save changes in the closed documents;
//                   'ask' to prompt the save changes dialogue;
//                   'no' to not save the changes;
var saveChanges = 'no'; 

var doc = activeDocument;

for (var i = documents.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (documents[i] != doc)
  {
    switch (saveChanges)
    {
      case 'yes':
        documents[i].close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);
        break;
      case 'ask':
        documents[i].close(SaveOptions.PROMPTTOSAVECHANGES);
        break;
      case 'no':
        documents[i].close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
        break;
      default:
        alert("saveChanges should've been 'yes', 'ask' or 'no' but instead was '" + saveChanges + "', aboring.");
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The script will close all inactive documents with or without saving them. Save the text as a `your_name.jsx` file to `*Path to Photoshop Folder*\Presets\Scripts\`, restart Photoshop and it'll be available at `File > Scripts > your_name`. Then you can run it from the menu, assign to a hotkey or use in an action.

Comment: This script is what i was looking for, minus a couple of things. Could the script ask if changes want to be saved before closing? And in addition, could pressing 'Cancel' stop the script? (so you can deal with that particular doc separately before restarting the script) Cheers!

Comment: I've updated my answer: now you can set `saveChanges` to the way you want the script to deal with edited files. In your case change `'no'` to `'ask'`. And pressing `Cancel` in a Save dialog will stop the script.

Answer (score 0):

As far I've seen there is no way of doing it such way.. but there is a small hack which might save u time

.. don't save your file the one which should not be closed

.. Make sure that file is in your first tab in Photoshop

.. Now close the main window (whole Photoshop)

.. Photoshop closes the windows in the reverse order. Hence by this way all saved files will be closed. And for the unsaved file, pop up box for all such file will be opened displaying the name of the current name of the tags respectively.

Hence, instead of closing each tab by pressing that small 'x' button and giving command to save or not.. this would be a great way to reduce Time

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a mac and there must be a similar way to do this on windows.  I minimize the file I want open into the dock and then option click one of the close file buttons on the top corner.  All the windows close except for the one in the dock.